# I need help figuring out why this C++ program will not build and run in codeblocks using the GNU CC compiler

Tags: c++

I do not understand why this C++ program will not build and run using Codeblocks and the GNU CC compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     string firstName;
     firstName = "Brandon";
     cout << "Hello " << firstName << endl;

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is vague. It implies some kind of error, but there is none shown.

Comment: Probably need to `#include <string>`?

Comment: Part of your toolchain is drunk.

Comment: Please be more specific.  Q: What are the exact error message(s) when you try to build?

Comment: I am new to programming. The error it shows is main.cpp|9|error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|

Comment: so string is not part of the iostream?

Comment: It's the missing include for <string> like Mats suggested above. And no, string has it's own header.

Comment: iostream has to do with streams. input/output.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just curious how come in the example I am following they didn't have to use the string header?

Comment: @user3408176 - `how come in the example I am following they didn't have to use the string header? `  Because in the example they were lucky.  There are headers that are required to *guarantee* compilation success.  Note the word *guarantee*.

Answer (score 1):

Want to use strings? You'll need to `#include` it.

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you use a class, function or such, you should look up (unless you have memorised it from using it many times) what header the class or type should.

For example, this page is the first hit in google for `C++ string`:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/
On this particular page, it shows `<string>` on the left-hand side of the page, to indicate that `<string>` is the header for this particular class.

Occassionally it is possible to use a class or function without including its correct header. It is, however, very bad form to RELY on such behaviour (unless you are in direct control of that header, of course). It appears that your example, when it does `#include <iostream>`, is indeed relying on that also doing `#include <string>`. It would then appear that this is not the case in your combination of OS & Compiler, hence you get an error.

And unfortunately, the error messages when you use `<<` for output of unknown types or otherwise make a mistake in that type of code, can be extremely unhelpful and often quite verbose as well (e.g. I missed out the `<<` between the actual output stream and some text the other day, and I got a good page full of error messages, none of which made much sense at all - but it gave me which line was wrong, and that was enough for me to eventually spot the error).